# Simple javaScript game to HTML output

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I made a simple JavaScript coin flip game on Codeacademy and just for a personal exercise I'm attempting to output it to HTML. It "works" fine but what I would like it to do is make it output the same way it outputted to the console log when I originally made the game. So say I "played" the game three times the output should look something along the lines of...

```
It took 3 flips to get tails!
Didn't get it on flip 1
Didn't get it on flip 2
It took 1 flip to get tails!
It took 5 flips to get tails!
Didn't get it on flip 1
Didn't get it on flip 2
Didn't get it on flip 3
Didn't get it on flip 4
```

However, the output is only displaying the "last" line of the game, so like in the example above the only thing output on HTML would be "Didn't get it on flip 4". Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o24nzpvw/

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        <script>


           function coinFlip(){
input = false;

do {
var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
flipTimes = 1;

while(coinFace === 0){
    flipTimes += 1;
    var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
}


if(flipTimes == 1){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It took " + flipTimes + " flip to get tails! <br>"; 
} else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It took " + flipTimes + " flips to get tails! <br>";
}

for (i = 1; i < flipTimes; i++){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Didn't get it on flip " + i + " <br>";
}

var input = false;
var input = confirm("Confirm to play again - Cancel to exit");
} 
while (input !== false); 

}
        </script>

        <button onclick="coinFlip()">Flip Coin!</button>

        <p id="output"></p>

    </body>
```

So how do I remedy this and "print" out EVERYTHING that happens when the user plays every game, like it initially did in the console log. I was thinking of trying something with adding to and returning an array but I'm not sure if that's the most elegant (or even plausible) solution. Thanks everyone!

Comment: [edited](http://jsfiddle.net/o24nzpvw/1/) Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the statements

```
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
```

Use

```
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the output lines to += to append and not remove the previous text:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Didn't get it on flip " + i + " <br>";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Didn't get it on flip " + i + " <br>";
```

Here is the working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/o24nzpvw/2/